# Angular2 url parameter encoding

Tags: angular

When navigating to a URL with a querystring like:

http://localhost:5000/search?q=test+test
the url suddenly becomes
http://localhost:5000/search?query=test%2Btest

Is it possible to alter this behaviour? I don't see anything wrong with the plus sign and I'd like to keep the sign in the url for various reasons.

Comment: Sounds like this issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11058

Answer (score 0):

As described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39666060/502256), you can provide your own custom url serializer by implementing the `UrlSerializer`. The serializer should look something like this:

```
class CustomUrlSerializer implements UrlSerializer {
    parse(url: string): UrlTree {
        // Custom code here
    }

    serialize(tree: UrlTree): string {
        // Custom code here
    }
}
```

You then need to provide your own implementation instead of the UrlSerializer:

```
providers: [
    { provide: UrlSerializer, useClass: CustomUrlSerializer },
    ...
]
```

Answer (score -1):

The plus sign is not a valid character in an url. But %2B is equivalent to + so at the reciving end it will be possible to parse it back to +

Comment: It's perfectly valid to have the plus sign in the path of an url