# Custom encoding for urls using Angular 2 Router (using a + sign in place of a space)

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am using an Angular 2 Router to update the query params in a URL for a search application. I am attempting to replace spaces in a query with + signs. However, + signs are getting encoded. For example:

```
this.router.navigatebyUrl('?q=one+two');
```

populates the URL with "?q=one%2Btwo".

In looking at the source code for Angular 2, it looks like the router converts the URL to a UrlTree [which uses encodeURIComponent() to encode the url](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/router/src/url_tree.ts#L360-L363). Because of this, it is impossible to prevent the default encoding.

My current process is that I change the route by doing navigateByUrl as seen above, and then listen for changes with:

```
this.routeSubscription = this.route.queryParams.subscribe((params: any) => {
  this.term = (params.q ? params.q : '');
});
```

Is there an alternate way to deal with query parameters that would allow me to use my own strategy for url encoding?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular 2 disable url encoding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41476193/angular-2-disable-url-encoding)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I was able to find a solution to my problem. You can make own custom url serializer by implementing the [UrlSerializer](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/UrlSerializer-class.html) class.

**Custom Url Serializer**

Create a custom url serializer like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomUrlSerializer implements UrlSerializer {

    constructor(private defaultUrlSerializer: DefaultUrlSerializer){}

    parse(url: string): UrlTree {
        // Custom code here
    }

    serialize(tree: UrlTree): string {
        // Custom code here
    }
}
```

Then, you just need to provide the CustomUrlSerializer in place of the UrlSerializer, which you can place in the AppModule providers array after importing both serializers.

```
providers: [
    { provide: UrlSerializer, useClass: CustomUrlSerializer },
       DefaultUrlSerializer
    ...
]
```

Now, when you call router.navigate or router.navigateByUrl, it will use your custom serializer for parsing and serializing.

**Using + signs as spaces**

To parse + signs as spaces:

```
parse(url: string): UrlTree {
    // Change plus signs to encoded spaces
    url = url.replace(/\+/g, '%20');
    // Use the default serializer that you can import to just do the 
    // default parsing now that you have fixed the url.
    return this.defaultUrlSerializer.parse(url)  
}
```

And for serializing:

```
serialize(tree: UrlTree): string {
    // Use the default serializer to create a url and replace any spaces with + signs
    return this.defaultUrlSerializer.serialize(tree).replace(/%20/g, '+');
}
```

[DefaultUrlSerializer](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/DefaultUrlSerializer-class.html)

Comment: Anyone encountered the error `ERROR in Invalid provider for undefined. useClass cannot be null.`?

Comment: I ran into that issue as well.  I added an answer to this question that explains my workaround.

Comment: I am getting 404 error on page refresh when using + as spaces, after uploaded my angular project on IIS, it is working fine in localhost. Can anyone provide suggestion to solve this?

Comment: I tried this solution in Angular 9.1 and it had complained, that it does not know `this.defaultSerializer`. Replacing `implements UrlSerializer` by `extends DefaultUrlSerializer` and `this.defaultUrlSerializer.parse` by `this.parse` as well as `this.defaultSerializer.serialize` by `this.serialize` has solved the problem. -- The reason of the problem seems to be that UrlSerializer is an interface and as such contains no implementation of that method.

Answer (score 6):

I ran into an issue specifying the custom provider.  There was apparently a circular dependency when compiling with the `--prod` flag causing an error with the text: `useClass cannot by null.` This is how I worked around that error:

In AppModule, define the following:

```
const customUrlSerializer = new CustomUrlSerializer();
const CustomUrlSerializerProvider = {
    provide: UrlSerializer,
    useValue: customUrlSerializer
};
```

Then in the providers array, add the provider you specified above.

```
...
providers: [CustomUrlSerializerProvider]
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried @Noahs solution in Angular 9.1 for avoiding that a `?` is replaced by `%3F`:

However, this **did not work**:

```
class CustomUrlSerializer implements UrlSerializer {
  parse(url: string): UrlTree {
    return this.defaultSerializer.parse(url)  
  }

  serialize(tree: UrlTree): string {
    return this.defaultSerializer.serialize(tree).replace(/%3F/g, '?');
  }
}
```

Angular had complained with following error message

```
client:159 src/app/app.module.ts:36:17 - error TS2339: Property 'defaultSerializer' does not exist on type 'CustomUrlSerializer'.
```

The following code **has worked for me**, though:

```
class CustomUrlSerializer extends DefaultUrlSerializer {
  parse(url: string): UrlTree {
    return super.parse(url)  
  }

  serialize(tree: UrlTree): string {
    return super.serialize(tree).replace(/%20/g, '+');
  }
}
```

There, I have replaced:

```
implements UrlSerializer --> extends DefaultUrlSerializer
this.defaultSerializer   --> super
```

Note: I have removed the following back-translation, since it replaces `?` by `%3F` before routing an URL, but we want to keep it in this case:

```
  parse(url: string): UrlTree {
    url = url.replace(/\?/g, '%3F'); // <--- removed
    ...
```