# Modifying the default URL encoding for Angular's router navigate method

Tags: angular

I need to customize how my URLs are encoded when calling the `navigate` method on the router.

I know I need to implement my own version of `UrlSerializer` and write a custom `serialize` method. My problem is really that the only method I wish to change is the `encode` method in `url_tree`.

```
export function encode(s) {
    return encodeURIComponent(s);
}
```

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/@angular/router/src/url_tree.ts#L344

In order to do this I need to copy + paste all the following methods from `url_tree` into my `CustomSerializer` because they are not exported:

`serialize`

`serializeQueryParams`

`Pair`

`pairs`

`serializeSegment`

`encode`

I've looked at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39666060/1128290) but it doesn't quite solve my problem as I want all the default behaviour except for the `encode` method.

Am I missing something here or is there a better way to solve this issue?

Comment: Have you considered extending an existing implementation? What behaviour precisely are you trying to change, and for what reason?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I would like to handle param encoding myself. My URL structure should resemble something `qs=test,my%20test,this%2Cthat`. I split the qs param by `,` to get the values. Angular's default encoding, however, encodes the commas

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular 2 disable url encoding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41476193/angular-2-disable-url-encoding)

Answer (score 6):

Angular2 by default uses encodeURIComponent() to encode queryParams in URL, you can avoid it by writing custom URL serializer and override default functionality.

In my case, I wanted to avoid Angular2 to avoid replacing comma(,) by (%2C). I was passing Query as lang=en-us,en-uk where it was getting converted to lang=en-us%2Cen-uk.

Here how I worked it out:

**CustomUrlSerializer.ts**

```
import {UrlSerializer, UrlTree, DefaultUrlSerializer} from '@angular/router';

export class CustomUrlSerializer implements UrlSerializer {
    parse(url: any): UrlTree {
        let dus = new DefaultUrlSerializer();
        return dus.parse(url);
    }

    serialize(tree: UrlTree): any {
        let dus = new DefaultUrlSerializer(),
        path = dus.serialize(tree);
        // use your regex to replace as per your requirement.
        return path.replace(/%2C/g,',');
      }
   }
```

Add below line to your main **appModule.ts**

```
import {UrlSerializer} from '@angular/router';
import {CustomUrlSerializer} from './CustomUrlSerializer';

@NgModule({
    providers: [{ provide: UrlSerializer, useClass: CustomUrlSerializer }]
})
```

This won't break your default functionality and take cares of URL as per your need.

Comment: In my case, the ! is not being replaced with %21 and is effectively breaking my code (and redirects me back to the root navigation path). Do you recommend using your method or submitting a bug request to the Angular team?

Comment: you can use this method and handle the URL encoding, try changing regex as per your requirement and let me know how it behaves.

Comment: Hi Am trying to change my '/' to '-' . Means Slash to Hyphen am trying for Seo friendly URL structure. While routing its perfect. But while reload the page. Component conflict is coming as an error. Any Idea.???