# Path parameters in Angular2

Tags: ajax, rest, http, angular

How are we meant to handle path parameters in Angular 2 when doing RESTful calls to a Web Service?

I've found the `URLSearchParams` object for query parameters but from what I have found it seems we'll have to make do with string-concatenation for the path itself. Like

```
let url = 'api/v1/something/' + encodeURIComponent(someParameter) + 
          '/etc/' + encodeURIComponent(anotherParam) + '/and/so/on';
```

Is there, included in angular2, something that does similar to:

```
let url = new URL('api/v1/something/{id}/etc/{name}/and/so/on', param1, param2);
```

I can of course create something similar myself but prefer if there is something included in angular2.

Comment: have you studied how routing works in angular 2 ? your question is not clear

Comment: @AmitSuhag Routing? The question is about doing AJAX request to a Web Service. Not routing.

Answer (score 4):

Indeed, you can use [string interpolation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and nearly exactly the same thing you suggest, assuming `id` and `name` are already set and encoded.

```
let url = new URL(`api/v1/something/${id}/etc/${name}/and/so/on`);
```

I'll note that currently [the ES6 URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/URL) class only supports `searchParams`, but has no notion of path parameters.

Also, I know of no method that will automatically encode your parameters without implementing [your own `QueryEncoder`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39541185/custom-encoding-for-urls-using-angular-2-router-using-a-sign-in-place-of-a-sp) with `URLSearchParams`

Answer (score 4):

If anybody is interested, this is what I ended up doing:

```
export interface PathParameters {
  [parameterName: string]: string;
}

export class Url {

  public static create(url: string, parameters: PathParameters) {
    const placeholders = url.match(/({[a-zA-Z]*})/g);
    placeholders.forEach((placeholder: string) => {
      const key = placeholder.substr(1, placeholder.length - 2);
      const value = parameters[key];
      if (!value) {
        throw new Error(`parameter ${key} was not provided`);
      }
      url = url.replace(placeholder, encodeURIComponent(value));
    });
    return url;
  }

}
```

How to use:

```
const url = Url.create('/api/cars/{carId}/parts/{partId}', {
    carId: carId,
    partId: partId
  });
```

Comment: Thanks, this saved my time as I was in the process of creating a similar method.