# How to handle parentheses in URL when navigating in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-routing

When we try to follow the url using name routing, then we get a navigation error.
Angular tries to find a named router, but it doesn't exist.
In other cases, everything works fine and we go to the 404 page.
Is it possible to somehow disable this behavior and go to the 404 page ?

**error demonstration**: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/base-angular-12-app-d93zm2?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

**steps to get error:**

- open console in stackblitz
- click on the red link called *"get url error"*
- there will be an error:

  ERROR
  Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: '2'
  Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: '2'

Comment: You might want to look into creating a custom UrlSerializer. There's an answer to a question very similar to yours: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39666060/2333617

Comment: Thank you, now we are catching this error with a custom service. 
But we still hope that there is a more native method

Comment: Hello. maybe you should consider an url like about-2 instead

Comment: Hello, it's important for us to have the expected behavior even if the url contains brackets with any value inside. It is irrational to foresee possible pages, if I understood you correctly

Comment: Voted to close as duplicate. There's no native method - a custom serialiser is the way to go with standard redirect to 404

Comment: Thank you, but we have implemented a similar functionality.
I want to know if it's possible to disable named routes with angular or redirect to 404 instead of error

Answer (score 1):

Using serialize turned out to be a really good way, thanks everyone!

UrlSerializer - https://angular.io/api/router/UrlSerializer
DefaultUrlSerializer - https://angular.io/api/router/DefaultUrlSerializer

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { DefaultUrlSerializer, UrlTree } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class CustomUrlSerializerService extends DefaultUrlSerializer {
  constructor() {
    super();
   }

  public parse(url: string): UrlTree {
    const urlSplit = url.split('?');
    const queryParams = urlSplit[1];
    let newUrl = this.replacer(decodeURI(urlSplit[0]));

    if (queryParams) {
      newUrl += `?${decodeURI(queryParams)}`;
    }

    return super.parse(newUrl);
  }

  public serialize(tree: UrlTree): string {
    return super.serialize(tree);
  }

  private replacer(str: string): string {
    return str.replace(/[()]/g, (c) => '%' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16));
  }
}
```

App.module.ts

```
...
providers: [
    ...
    { provide: UrlSerializer, useClass: CustomUrlSerializerService }
],
```

Answer (score -1):

use [router.navigate()](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#navigate) instead;

example use case:

```
this._router.navigate(['/about(2)']);
```